# When people select different close reasons, what will the final reason displayed be?

Tags: support, closed-questions

Just wanted to know, when different people select different reasons to close a question, what's the reason finally displayed? Is it the one that received the first close vote? What happens for questions closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is whichever receives the most votes for a reason. If it is tied (i.e. 2 as NARQ, 2 not constructive, 1 too localized), then it is the first one to vote. If it's a duplicate that it gets closed as, it (sometimes) lists both duplicates in the question, and that is the reason. If it is voted as OT and sent to another site, it goes there.

For "exact duplicate" votes, if multiple questions are chosen, then all of these links are inserted into the "Possible duplicate:" text on the question. (This was pointed out by slhck in the comments)

Comment: Thanks! How about if (theoretically) more than 2 threads are voted as being ones a question is duplicating? I don't think I've seen more than 2 duplicates mentioned so far, so is this a system limit and does it just pick the first two (or the 2 with most votes), ignoring the rest?

Comment: When I see it with 2 duplicate threads, I usually have the last vote and choose the first one on the list... So that part I don't know. If you want, make a question on here, and we can have  people VTC with different reasons as a test. Just link us in Chat

Comment: I can do that, but is it allowed? Also, would need to think of a question that can be marked as being a duplicate of more than 2 previous questions. Perhaps a mod can tell us without needing to experiment by cluttering up the (meta) site with useless questions. :)

Comment: We need more Meta here...

Comment: You also raised an interesting point. It would be nice to know whether a mod decides if more than one duplicate should be linked to, or does the system do it based on some heuristic (say a 3-2 split between votes for 2 threads)?

Comment: I would assume the 3 votes are more powerful then the 2

Comment: If multiple questions are chosen by close voters, then all of these links are inserted into the "Possible duplicate:" text on the question.

Comment: @slhck: Ah, so we *could* have more than 2 questions linked to as duplicates? (An unlikely situation, I admit, which is probably why I've never seen it happen yet.)

Comment: @Karan I actually often do this if I find another duplicate: Just vote to close as that and there will be two listed, automatically. Granted, it really doesn't happen often

Comment: If a question is closed as a duplicate of _three_ other questions, doesn't it stand to reason that some of the _them_ should also be closed as duplicates? And, if so, why wouldn't you just close-as and display-the-link-to the "master" question?

Comment: @AlEverett: That does make sense, but I just wanted to know what will happen if something like this were to transpire (i.e., will *all* 3 be listed as duplicates).

Comment: @Karan Only one way to find out

Comment: @Luke: [Happy](http://meta.superuser.com/questions/6160/top-questions-of-the-week-test-question)? ;)

Comment: @Karan I am, but I had to VTC as a dupe ;)

Comment: Heh. :) Anyway, [looks like](http://i.stack.imgur.com/Bwo9C.png) it *will* add as many duplicate links as there are votes for distinct questions, so that's that.

Comment: Ha, I happened to come across [this page](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/05/linking-duplicate-questions) *just now*, and here's what Jeff had to say about it: "Remember, it takes **5** close votes from 3,000+ reputation users to close a question, but they don’t all have to agree on the reason. (The reason with the most votes, however, will be shown when the question is finally closed. *Yes yes, I know, you’re programmers so you are immediately wondering what happens if all five votes are for five different reasons. Stop that right now!*)" Sorry Jeff, I had to know! :D